# AngularJS How to prevent duplicated http requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm struggling for the past day with some weird situation.
What's happening is that for an http request to an API on a remote server occasionally duplicate requests are being sent.
Can anyone please provide help on how to avoid these duplicated requests?

Here is an example of a function that I use on a factory:

```
factory.getAllConsultedClientsLogs = function(oParams) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('url/to/api', oParams)
        .success(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function() {
            deferred.reject("Error! @factory.getAllConsultedClientsLogs");
        });

return deferred.promise;

};
```

...and an example of a function using the above indicated on a controller:

```
$scope.openConsultedClientsLogsModal = function(operator, date) {

    if (angular.isDefined(operator) && angular.isDefined(date)) {

        RrAuditingFactory.getAllConsultedClientsLogs({'operator':operator,'date':date}).then(function(promise) {

            if (angular.isObject(promise) && angular.isDefined(promise.error) && promise.error == 0) {

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'path/partial',
                    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, logsResult) {
                        $scope.logsResult = logsResult;
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        logsResult: function() {
                            return promise.result;
                        }
                    }
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                }, function () {
                });

            } else {
                ErrorContext.setError(promise.errorMsg);
            }

        }, function(promise) {
            ErrorContext.setError(promise);
        });

    } else {

        ErrorContext.setError();

    }

};
```

Thank you in advance.. hope that anyone could help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your link:

> ```
>     $scope.fnRowCallback = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
>
>         $('td:eq(4)', nRow).bind('click', function() {
>             $scope.$apply(function() {
>                 $scope.openConsultedClientsLogsModal(aData.Operator, aData.LogDate);
>             });
>         });
>
>         return nRow;
>     };
> ```

You can unbind before doing the bind, this way you will prevent duplicates.
Try like this:

```
    $scope.fnRowCallback = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {



        //add this unbind to your code
        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).unbind("click");


        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).bind('click', function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.openConsultedClientsLogsModal(aData.Operator, aData.LogDate);
            });
        });

        return nRow;
    };
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense... I tested with the unbind and it fix my problem. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: @aqua,Am I missing something in the question? The code snippet in the answer isn't related to the one in question.

Comment: @jijil-kakkadathu I guess you are missing the date this question was posted. It has been almost 5 years now... and it's marked as resolved...

Answer (score 2):

i have faced this problem, and you can resolve it like this :

check if you have declared ng-controller twice , you need to declare it just one time
check if you have declared data-ng-click , if so , you need to replace it with ng-click
that's it

Comment: I had the same problem and I saw I used ng-controller **AND**  `$routeProvider.when('/route', { controller: 'MyController', ... });`

Comment: The same for me: I specified controller name in `$routeProvider` and in HTML - that is why request doubled

Answer (score 0):

I tend to return an object from a factory, so in your case I'd do something like:

```
module.factory('clientsLogs', function($q, $http) {

  return {
    getAllConsulted: function(oParams) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post('url/to/api', oParams)
        .then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function() {
            deferred.reject("Error! @factory.getAllConsultedClientsLogs");
        });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }

});
```

and then in your controller something like:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, clientsLogs) {
  clientLogs.getAllConsulted({}).then(function(){...})
}
```

Might not help you but I've never had any problems with duplicate calls doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm doing it that way... The thing is that in some cases it duplicates calls. So, I would like to know if anyone could help me on how to prevent duplicated http requests? With a decorator or with a modified http service? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and I saw I used ng-controller **AND** `$routeProvider.when('/route', { controller: 'MyController', ... });`