# How to prevent sending duplicate request with a single click in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I have an angularJs application that has an api call with a click on a link . but everytime i click on the link it sends 2 same api calls to the server. Why this occurs and how can i resolve this.

**my service is like:** SomethingService

```
 function getData() {
    return apiSettings.getApiInformation().then(function (response) {
        var url = response.data.Url + "/odata/Something?$expand=Something";

            var data = {
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                token: response.data.Token,
                data: {},
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                headers: {
                         "accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.Token
                       },
                dataType: "json",
                success: {},
                error: {},
                complete: {},
                fail:{}
            };
            return $http(data);
    });   
}
```

**Api Settings :**

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
.factory('apiSettings', apiSettings);

apiSettings.$inject = ['$http'];

function apiSettings($http) {
    return {
            getApiInformation: function () {
               return $http.get(baseUrl+ '/api/GetApiInformation', {cache: true});
            }
    }

}
```

**SomethingController:**

```
var vm = this;
function getSlots(filterCriteria, selectedValue) {

    somethingService.getData().then(function (response) {
        if (response && response.value.length > 0) {               
            vm.someData = response.value;
        }
    });
```

**View:**
clicking on this link calls getSlots that sends duplicate request

```
 <a ui-sref="something" class="action-icons" id="slotNav"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-fw"></i>
something
</a>
```

this view displays data

```
<div ng-repeat="data in vm.someData">
        <p> {{data.Name}}</p>
 </div>
```

**Issue:** For a single trigger browser sends duplicate requests  like the following. the first call doesn't have callback but the second call has callback:

```
someuls?$expand=something&_=1432722651197   
someuls?$expand=something&_=1432722651197
```

Comment: Which call is being duplicated `odata/something` or `api/GetApiInfo..`? And why are you using both angular's `$http` and jQuery's `$.ajax`?

Comment: odata/something is being duplicated. For every odata get call there are 2 calls completed. every other things are works fine. It does the same thing when i use $http for both.

Comment: The first thing I would change is the `odata/something` call to use angular's `$http` service. `$http` lives within angular's domain (in regards to scope) so it knows when to trigger the digest loop which is what drives angular (including data binding)

Comment: It does the same thing when i use $http for both

Comment: Please add the code that is triggering these functions (likely controller) and also the corresponding markup/html

Comment: It seems getSlots is being called twice, you need it look into how it is being called. This could be the issue.

Comment: Corresponding controller and view code added @Brocco

Comment: Where is the state/route defined? I am still not seeing the code where getSlots is being called.

Comment: see all corresponding codes here : http://plnkr.co/edit/ucBZQYPvcn9MmMbGUUJX @Brocco

Comment: Only thing I can see is that you might be navigating to that controller multiple times? try putting `console.log` msgs here in app.js: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {`

Comment: It is not navigating to controller twice. only executing  return $.ajax(data); occurring 2 calls.@Brocco

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I fixed by checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29768683). I had declared "ng-controller" in HTML as well as routed to it using routeProvider. Fixed the issue by removing the "ng-controller" property in HTML.

Hope this helps.